# Spring Data JPA method for getting the Entity with Joined table

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa

I have very specific question. I have Entity "A" with some variables and `OneToMany` relations to other table "B". I want to create query to get `id` of entity "A" and value from table "B" using Locale parameter.

Table B have a translations to entity.

Example:

```
Entity A:
  id: 1
  var_1: "SDFA"
  OneToMany
  List<B> tabParam;

Entity B:
  id: 2
  value: "ASDF2"
  locale: "en-EN"
  id_A: 1

Entity B:
  id: 3
  value: "ASDF"
  locale: "fr-FR"
  id_A: 1
```

I want to merge those both table to get for locale "fr-FR":

```
[ {id: 1, value: "ASDF" }]
```

Now I got:

```
[{ id: 1, tabParam: [ {value: "ASDF2"},{value : "ASDF"}]}]
```

My method from JPA repository:

```
List<A> findByTabParamLocale(Locale locale)
```

I am using Locale Hibernate converter from entity to table and from table to entity without any problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Base on `EntityB.id_A + EntityB.locale` is unique. Use bellow projection code to get want you want :

```
// define the dto interface
public interface LocaleDto {
  Integer getId();
  String getLocale();
}

// define a interface method in your repository
@Query("select a.id, b.locale from EntityA a join a.tabParam b where b.locale = ?1")
List<LocaleDto> findByTabParamLocale(Locale locale)

// or use
@Query("select id_A as id, locale from EntityB where locale = ?1")
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Great answer! I used second Query (first works as well but in this scenario seconds fits better). I have to change it: `@Query("select id_A as id, locale as locale from EntityB where local = ?1")` . With locale without as locale I got null

Comment: Rename `local` to `locale`. `locale as locale` is not neccessary, just use `locale` is fine.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your question description

Basically you want to get Id of Entity A. Also your JPA method is look ok only you have need change to getting the Id of Entity A.

Instead of

```
 List<A> findByTabParamLocale(Locale locale);
```

Use This

```
AIdDto findByTabParamLocaleProjectedBy(Locale locale);
```

AIdDto is projection interface. You will create as follows

```
public AIdDto {

  Integer getId(); // This is id getter method of Enity A.
}
```

For more detail. Please refer the spring data jpa reference doc.

https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#projections

Through the projection you can try using create custom project value mapper bean like that

Modify AIdDto

```
 public AIdDto {

  @Value("#{target.id}")
  Integer getId();

  @Value("#{@projectionBean.getLocale(target)}")
  String getLocale();
}
```

Create ProjectionBean

```
@Component
class ProjectionBean {

  String getLocale(EntityA entityA) {
    //Write the logic for find the exact EntityB Locale
  }
```

}

But this is not optimised solution

Comment: Thank you @Dhiren for your answer. I got: PropertyReferenceException: No property projectedBy found for type Locale. Should I use any annotation or write something differently?

Comment: Can you use 

      AIdDto findByTabParam_Locale(Locale locale);

Comment: Simple AidDto generated error with nouniqueId. With List<AidDto> i got result: `[
    {
        "id": 1
    },
    {
        "id": 2
    }
]`  . I want to get id with values from entity B. Projection works with join tables or works only for one entity?

Comment: Little bit tricky with get exact match with join table through the spring data jpa projection.Its possible extract the value through join table as well for that. Need to write custom value mapper bean. Better to use mentioned above @rj-hwang answer